# How do I add unicode to an ID3 tag using ruby?

Tags: ruby, utf-16, id3, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to add a unicode title to an ID3 tag (v2.3) of an MP3. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do it. According to [id3.org's id3v2 page](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.3.0#head-1a37d4a15deafc294208ccfde950f77e47000bca), Unicode strings have to begin with the Unicode BOM.

I'm currently trying id3v2, but the tag saves as gibberish.

I'd like to do it in ruby, but a linux utility would also be acceptable.

**Update:**
I figured out a solution using the [id3lib-ruby](http://id3lib-ruby.rubyforge.org/) gem. It's listed below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: found a slightly more elegant solution
I figured out a solution that works using the [id3lib-ruby](http://id3lib-ruby.rubyforge.org/) gem.

```
tag = ID3Lib::Tag.new('talk.mp3')
utf16 = Iconv.conv('UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8', str) #UTF-16BE doesn't have BOM
tag << {:id => :TIT2, :textenc => 1, :text => utf16}
```

<strike>utf16 = Iconv.conv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', str)

<strike>utf16_no_bom = utf16[2..-1] #removes the BOM</strike> 
tag << {:id => :TIT2, :textenc => 1, :text => utf16_no_bom}</strike>

This usage comments inside [id3lib.rb](https://github.com/robinst/id3lib-ruby/blob/id3lib-ruby-0.6.0/lib/id3lib.rb) (line 105) are a bit misleading. If you set :textenc => 1 and include the UTF-16 BOM (\xFF\xFE), then you'll end up with a gibberish character at the beginning of your tag.

Comment: If you want a non-hacky solution, look at [taglib-ruby](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby). Tt's based on TagLib and has full Unicode support (with ID3v2.4, which allows to store text as UTF-8). Please open an issue on github if there's a problem :).

Comment: I saw taglib-ruby a couple months ago. Looks pretty good. I'll be switching to it when I upgrade the project that I was working on.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to [`encode()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001113) the string?

Comment: Might it be time to switch to 1.9.2? :-)